# Alert when code is running background in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

Working with Google App script and Javascript, I managed to retrieve xls Gmail attachments, convert it to google sheets, send an warning email to some recipients, insert an event with the Google Drive folder link when a new attachment is added to it, and at the end I managed with a standalone script to import some of the data coming from such xls file converted to a main Google Sheet where one operator is working h24 ( updating some data to be forwarded later on and during the service itself).
The standalone script run every 30 minutes to check incoming mail ( the schedule for the next day or days), and when it find it, it execute the code.
The lock service is not available on standalone scripts up to now, so I cannot lock the document, so I wish to display a message to the user that the script is about to run and not edit anything, since other scripts bounded to the Spreadsheet are using the Lock service, and so the result could be quite disappointing. I searched info regarding this "alert", but I cannot find a clue about it.
Could you address me somewhere?
I could add a menu function instead of a standalone script, and the operator could select "Import data" and that's it, but I wish to automate the operation in background.

Comment: Maybe an alternative solution could be to simply change the spreadsheet to display "Warning! Executing code!" in a certain cell whenever it runs, or to change the background colors of all cells to red while executing?

Comment: How about adding a new menu called "SCRIPT IS RUNNING!!!!" and remove the menu when the script completes. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

Comment: Good points, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the HTML Service. I don't know much about it myself but I think the following may do what you need:

At the top of you .gs file:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var htmlApp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("html");     
var status = "Loading....."
 htmlApp.data = status;
 ss.show(htmlApp.evaluate()
 .setWidth(300)
 .setHeight(200));
```

At the end (just before the last brace):

```
var status = "Finished!"
 htmlApp.data = status;
 ss.show(htmlApp.evaluate()
 .setWidth(300)
 .setHeight(200));
```

In a new HTML script file named 'html':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Updating..</h2>
<p id="status">(innerHTML).</p>
<div id="imageico"></div>
<script>
var imageContainer = document.getElementById("imageico");
if (<?= data ?> != "Finished!"){
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Running script, please wait..";
} else {
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Finished! You can now close the window.";
closeBtn();

}  
   function closeBtn(){
   var button = document.createElement("INPUT");
    button.setAttribute("type", "button");
    button.setAttribute("value", "Close");
    button.setAttribute("onclick", "closeWindow();");
    imageContainer.appendChild(button);
    }

function closeWindow(){
google.script.host.close();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDITED** Based on comments

In your .gs file:

```
 function test() {

    htmlApp("","");

/*
*
*  Put your code in here....
*
*/     

  Utilities.sleep(3000); // change this value to show the "Running script, please wait.." HTML window for longer time.

  htmlApp("Finished!",""); 

  Utilities.sleep(3000);  // change this value to show the "Finished! This window will close automatically. HTML window for longer time.

  htmlApp("","close"); // Automatically closes the HTML window.

}

 function htmlApp (status,close) {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var htmlApp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("html");     
      htmlApp.data = status;
      htmlApp.close = close;
      ss.show(htmlApp.evaluate()
     .setWidth(300)
     .setHeight(200));
}
```

In the HTML script file named 'html':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
<h2>Updating..</h2>
<p id="status">(innerHTML).</p>
<div id="imageico"></div>
<script>
var imageContainer = document.getElementById("imageico");
if (<?= data ?> != "Finished!"){
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Running script, please wait..";
} else {
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Finished! This window will close automatically.";
}     
if (<?= close ?> == "close"){
google.script.host.close();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Have a look at this [Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QphYHr_sYNrHntUJOX7_cFbxzPxaEL2blPpnI-Td_sQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: It works, that is a good solution! I tried adding setTimeout with closing function, in order to achieve self closing message, but it close the html too soon despite I set 10000 as time, then I tried to use Utilities.sleep in the else statement and then the function closeWindow, but it freeze the html and it is not closing at all, I searched here around about this possibilities but nothing seems coming out. Anyway a short click on the close button is a very good solution, thanks again.

Comment: Do you mean you want the window to close automatically when the script finishes instead of showing a close button?

Comment: I would like show the window for let's say 3 second over the time required tu run the code, if it show only for the running time it is barely visible, I wish to display what was going on

Comment: Done.. Please make a copy of the [Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QphYHr_sYNrHntUJOX7_cFbxzPxaEL2blPpnI-Td_sQ/edit?usp=sharing) again. Please note that the logic has changed quite a bit.

Comment: Well it is great, I do have to improve my knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: I was a complete beginner too. I only started learning how to program, Javascript and Google Scripts 6 months ago! It wouldn't have been possible without the help of this site.

Comment: Just a note... this will not work with onEdit simple trigger. It errors on `ss.show(htmlApp.evaluate().setWidth(300).setHeight(125));` because show needs permission and that is restricted on simple triggers. Solution is to use installable trigger of spreadsheet On Edit. In my case it took >20 seconds to trigger so it was not an acceptable solution for me.

Comment: It took >20 to trigger or to show the HTML window? The implementation would depend on your code.

Comment: @JamesD it took greater than 20 seconds to trigger the script to run using installable triggers. My workaround was to use toast for those scenarios and what you provided in all others. One thing I would like to do is modify the appearance of the pop up. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any methods or sample scripts regarding your concern. But this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alertprompt) about `alert` might help. It will open a dialog box in the user's editor with the given message and an "OK" button. However, this method suspends the server-side script while the dialog is open and the script will resume after the user dismisses the dialog.

You may also execute [alert dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#alert_dialogs) before running your script.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show alert', 'showAlert')
      .addToUi();
}

function showAlert() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.alert(
     'Please confirm',
     'Are you sure you want to continue?',
      ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
    // User clicked "Yes".
    ui.alert('Confirmation received.');
  } else {
    // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('Permission denied.');
  }
}
```