# Good Sheets How to add a notification while a function is executing that automatically closes when the function "Execution succeeded"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I don't have an example script but I'm wondering if there's a way to create notification popup while a function is executing that automatically closes when the function's Execution has succeeded?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785183/alert-when-code-is-running-background-in-google-sheet

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function notification() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.toast('Running', '', -1);
  Utilities.sleep(10000);
  ss.toast('Completed');
}
```

Comment: The `Completed` toast won't disappear automatically, @WLyman, I would modify the last line to something like`ss.toast('Completed', "", 2);`

Comment: That one should disappear after five seconds

Comment: While the documentation does agree with this - I tested it and it stayed. I wonder if it's just documentation or and Apps Script issues but either way specifying the timeout forces the close.